# TimePicker display different time

Tags: java, android, timepicker, android-timepicker

I have make a `editText`,used to display `TimePicker`.

```
static Calendar c = null;
static int hour;
static int min;
static int hour1, min1;

 time = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.time);

  time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Fragment fragDialog = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TimePicker");
                        if (fragDialog == null) { // Fragment not added
                            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
                        } else {
                            // already active
                        }
                    }
                });

  public static class TimePick extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            c = Calendar.getInstance();
            hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, min, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }


        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourofDay, int minute) {
            time.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
            hour1 = hourofDay;
            min1 = minute;
        }
    }
```

When save `button` is clicked, it will pass the selected time to `AlarmManager`, and display the minute and hour.

```
 save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Calendar alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
                        alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour1);
                        alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min1);
                        alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), hour1 + "" + min1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyReceiver.class);
                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent, 0);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().ALARM_SERVICE);
                        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                    }
                });

                alert.setView(promptView);
                alert.show();
             }
```

Assume I select time with hour 11 , min with 20 and click save, the Toast display `1120` correctly. But in second time, I click save without clicking the time `editText`, the `Toast` should display `00` but it display the previous result `1120` instead.

Comment: Your `hour1` and `min1` are global variables. So thats why they shows the old time.

Comment: @DeepakGoyal If I remove the static, I get error. What is the correct way to write ?

Comment: you can reassign the value to the variables to `0` in `onClick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell for sure because, on one hand, I don't have the full code, and on the second hand, I don't know what you mean by 'the second time'.

But you're variables are declared as **static**, that means that even if you destroy that object, the next time you instantiate a new object, those variables will have the values they had on the previous instance. That is because, static variables are shared and preserved across all instances of the same class.

```
public class Foo {
    static int bar;
}

Foo a = new Foo();
a.bar = 3;

Foo b = new Foo();
Log.d("tag", "value = " + b.bar); // this will print 3
```

EDIT:

If you still want to use those variables that way, you need to clean them first, somewhere, but it's up to you to decide the best place.

```
hour1 = 0;
min1 = 0;
```

Comment: I have a button used to display dialog and the time editText is inside the dialog. When save button is clicked, it will shown in the listView.